# When should I add a subdomain to my website?

Tags: domains, subdomain

I'm working on the correction of a website. To keep it simple I added a subdomain to it and use it to install the template I was working on. Now - after fininshing the work, I'm thinking about keeping it (Order Form) on this subdomain and consider to simply delete the original one from the website. My question is about any problems this might cause. What are the pros & cons of dividing the website in subdomains - is there any disadvantage of doing so?

Right now it looks like this:

```
www.example.com
www.orderform.example.com
```

I'm not sure if and when it would makes sence to create further subdomain for the other functions of the website?

Comment: Just use a folder `www.exampledomain.com/orderform` and place an `index.html` file inside of the folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Analogy is my best friend...**

When I think of subdomains, I think of a big building for a corporation. Inside that big building, there are different departments that are devoted to different things.

For example, in company CompanyX, there might be an accounting department, a testing department and a human resources department. If this corporation was a domain, the subdomains might be like the departments: `accounting.companyx.com`, `testing.companyx.com`, and `hr.companyx.com`.

What you don't want to do is create a subdomain for a very small feature of your site. At least, for organization's sake, it doesn't make much sense.

Consider the corporation analogy again. Our imaginary domain would not divide into 500 subdomains for every employee in every department (ex. `johndoe.companyx.com`, `bobdylan.companyx.com`, etc).

While you can create as many subdomains as you want, they are intended to have the option of an entirely different set of routing options from your A record (`example.com`). This means that `suba.example.com` can work very much independently from the A record, almost as if it's a completely different website.

I would reserve subdomains for larger subsets of your operation, and keep smaller functions of your site as just plain pages or subdirectories in your A record domain. In the example you gave, I would not create an entire subdomain for an order form, rather just a subdirectory: `example.com/orderform`.